# Ionic 3 - Native: tried calling / accessing <plugin-name> but's plugin but it's not installed

Tags: angular, google-maps, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

To summarize my long story, I'm trying to add a google maps and the screen goes blank ... I thought it was a **problem with that specific plugin but not** ... when I did the google chrome inspection (running the app on a device android) I realized that I had several warning of "Native" ... and I can not find the problem! I need your help, maybe some of you already ran into these warnings sometime in your life:

**(see image with error in link please:)**
---->[plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzS8K.png)<----

This is my list of installed plugins:

```
> cordova plugin ls
card.io.cordova.mobilesdk 2.1.0 "CardIO"
com.googlemaps.ios 2.6.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk 3.5.0 "PayPalMobile"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-apprate 1.3.0 "AppRate"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.4 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.8.11 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.8 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.2.9 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2-dev "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-stripe 1.5.3 "cordova-plugin-stripe"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.2.1 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.3.3 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
```

My ionic info:

```
cli packages: (...)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4 ios copy 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v6.9.4
npm        : 3.10.10
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Part of my package.json

```
    "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-rate": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/paypal": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/stripe": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "android-versions": "^1.2.1",
    "card.io.cordova.mobilesdk": "^2.1.0",
    "com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk": "^3.5.0",
    "cordova-ios": "~4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-apprate": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.8.11",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.7.4",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.0.8",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk.git#2.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git",
    "cordova-plugin-stripe": "^1.5.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.2.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "ion-affix": "^1.1.1",
    "ionic": "3.20.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.7.3",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "localforage": "^1.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.3.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "woocommerce-api": "^1.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.0",
    "ionic": "3.20.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  },
```

NOTE: I have already reviewed many forums, and in all I have read that I have to put the map after platform.ready () and so I did ... but it still does not work, ... same with these other plugins that I showed in the first image.

NOTE 2: I have also run with --prod and nothing (`ionic cordova run android`)

NOTE 3: The app is a virtual store, which generally runs well, so my surprise when I saw so many warnings

Comment: What version of the `@ionic-native/google-maps` do you use?

Comment: @wf9a5m75 `"@ionic-native/google-maps": "4.2.0"` < in my package.json .... I added my package.json in question

Comment: The latest version is `@ionic-native/google-maps : 4.6.3`.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/google-maps

Comment: You should use the same version for all other `@ionic-native/...@4.6.0` plugins exclude the maps.  The maps plugin only `@4.6.3`. Try it.